# Hodge theorem for cohomology group on holomorphic vector bundles and harmonic forms

Tags: vector-bundles, hodge-theory

Consider the holomorphic vector bundle $\pi: E \rightarrow M $ where $M$ is a complex manifold of dimension $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}M = m$. Denote by $\Omega^{p,q} (M)$ the bundle for bidegree $p,q$ holomorphic and antiholomorphic forms. The complex Hodge star is given as $\bar{\ast}: \Omega^{p,q} (M) \rightarrow \Omega^{m-p,m-q}(M)$. Now consider the case when we have $E$ valued antiholomorphic $q$ forms then the hodge star operator is $\ast_{E}:\Omega^{0,q}(M)\bigotimes E \rightarrow \Omega^{n,n-q}\bigotimes E^{*}=\Omega^{0,n-q}\bigotimes K_{M} \bigotimes E^{*} $ where $E^{*}$ is the dual bundle and $K_{M}=\Omega^{n,0}(M) $ is the canonical line bundle.
Denote by, $A^{p,q}$ the space of sections of the bundle $\Omega^{p,q}(M)$.
Defining an operator, $\bar{\partial}_{E}:A^{0,q}(E)\rightarrow A^{0,q-1}(E) $ and its dual as $\bar{\partial}^{*}_{E}=(-1)^{q} \ast^{-1}_{E} \bar{\partial}_{K_{M}\bigotimes E^{*}}\ast_{E}$ where $A^{0,n-q}(K_{M}\bigotimes E^{*})\xrightarrow{\bar{\partial}^{*}_{K_{M}\bigotimes E^{*}}} A^{0,n-q-1}(K_{M}\bigotimes E^{*})$.
Now the laplacian $\Delta_{E}=\bar{\partial_{E}}\bar{\partial^{*}_{E}+} \bar{\partial^{*}_{E}}\bar{\partial_{E}}$. The kernel set of this laplacian operator are harmonic $(0,q)$ forms with values in $E$. 
According to Hodge theorem, the $k$ th cohomology group of a complex manifold is isomorphic to the space of $k$ degree harmonic forms. how does this apply in the present case for holomorphic vector bundles. Should we think of Dolbeault cohomology group? Or locally free sheaves? 
What cohomology group is isomorphic to the space of such harmonic forms?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Can you elaborate? By the way the identification by Hodge theorem is not canonical; you can use any elliptic operator, not just the Dolbeault operator.

Comment: Here we have the specific space for $\Delta_{E}$ harmonic $(0,q)$ forms. The ques. is what cohomology group is this space isomorphic to (applying Hodge theorem of course)?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question:  the space of harmonic forms is isomorphic to the cohomology of the complex you started with, which is the Dolbeault complex.  As you say, this is exactly what Hodge theory tells you.  This is all nicely explained in the first volume of Claire Voison's book "Complex Algebraic Geometry."  Also, some of your formulas are not correct: for example, as you've written it you can't compose the del-bar operator with it's adjoint... Perhaps this is a source of your confusion.